# What might keep a user from being able to drag and drop a document into a document library?

Tags: 2013, document-library, drag-and-drop

I have a user who is suddenly unable to drag and drop documents into a shared document library. I recently updated the main page of the site, but the changes were purely cosmetic and I did not change any permissions or touch this library at all.

She has Full Control of the site and the library has no special restrictions, so I do not believe it is an issue with permissions. Note that she can still add documents to this library through the use of the New Document button.

I and another user I spoke to can still drag and drop to the library. I have tried in both Chrome and Internet Explorer and it works for me.

Is there something I may have missed that could be causing this issue? We are using Sharepoint 2013.